# Symfony2 inheriting more than one bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle

how can I inherit more than one bundle?

I've searched everywhere but nothing :(.

Code for inheriting one bundle which everybody probably knows

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
}
```

Now i want to inherit `KnpKnpPaginatorBundle` also, so i can change the `sliding.html.twig` for my own personal needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit only 1 bundle with getParent().

The possible solutions:

- Add another bundle to inherit KnpPaginator
- Change sliding.html.twig using [Overriding bundle templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates)

Comment: I used your second option to achieve my goals. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony does not allow multiple inheritance